# cakephp 3.0 $this->output function does not exist error

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-3.0, helper, view-helpers

I am using the image helper of 2.x in my cakephp 3.x application but  i am facing a problem with this that in my cakephp 2.x the function return the value as below code

```
return $this->output(sprintf($this->Html->_tags['image'], $this->webroot($relfile), $this->Html->_parseAttributes($htmlAttributes, null, '', ' ')), $return);
```

but in cakephp 3.x output and  _parseAttributes function is removed so i dont know how to use these two function in cakephp 3.x

_parseAttributes function contain the image related data like 'class', 'alt' other things

i have searched a lot on net for output function in cake 3.x but did not find any successfull solution please try to help me

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your expected html code ?

Comment: expected code is    
<img src="/job_portal_28Oct2015/job_portal/uploads/resized/50x29_07618091cf8654a8c3f57b45b2daa1f8.jpg" alt="thumb">

Answer (score 1):

### Use the `Html` helper

There's nothing in your example code that justifies the use of custom code for generating the tag, so you could simply use the `Html` helper instead

```
// ...

class YourCustomHelper extends Helper
{
    public $helpers = [
        'Html',
        // ...
    ];

    public function someMethod($relfile, array $htmlAttributes)
    {
        $options = $htmlAttributes + ['pathPrefix' => false];
        return $this->Html->image($url, $options);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note the use of the `pathPrefix` option, since it looks like you want to point to a custom path, you should disable it, as otherwise you may end up with the default image base URL being prepended to the path.

### Custom tags and attributes

If you'd really need a custom solution that isn't already covered by other helpers, then the replacement for `output()` and `_parseAttributes()` are `return` and string templates.

For the sake of supplying an example, here's a trimmed down one of what `HtmlHelper::image()` does:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\View\StringTemplateTrait;

// ...

class YourCustomHelper extends Helper
{
    use StringTemplateTrait;

    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'templates' => [
            'someTemplate' => '<img src="{{url}}"{{attrs}}/>',
        ],
        // ...
    ];

    public $helpers = [
        'Url',
        // ...
    ];

    public function someMethod($relfile, array $htmlAttributes = [])
    {
        $url = $this->Url->assetUrl($relfile);

        $templater = $this->templater();
        return $templater->format('someTemplate', [
            'url' => $url,
            'attrs' => $templater->formatAttributes($htmlAttributes),
        ]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This should be pretty much self explantory, you include the `StringTemplateTrait` that holds the templating functionality, define a custom template, and format it using the templater.

Note the use of the `Url` helper, it will do all the necessary stuff like encoding the URL, timestamping it, adding the webroot path, etc...

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Configuration options](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#configuration-options)**
- **[Source > \Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper::image()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.3/src/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L809)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper::assetUrl()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.Helper.UrlHelper.html#_assetUrl)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\StringTemplate::format()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.StringTemplate.html#_format)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\StringTemplate::formatAttributes()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.StringTemplate.html#_formatAttributes)**
- **[Cookbook > Appendices > 3.0 Migration Guide > Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#helper)**